# Scraping current date from website using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, web, web-scraping

Error
[image]

Librarys
[image]

I need the date of the current day. I do not want to place it inside a variable to be able to have it work, instead I would like that variable to be Date or in its default String.

```vb
Sub WEB()

    Dim IE As Object
    Dim allelements As Object

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    IE.navigate "http://www.fechadehoy.com/venezuela"
    Do Until IE.ReadyState = 4
        DoEvents
    Loop
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
    IE.document.getElementById ("date")
    IE.Visible = True
    Set IE = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

The website is http://www.fechadehoy.com/venezuela

I only need the date of this page. I am not interested in any other element of the macro.

I just need to extract the current date and get it in a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the answer given by @Siddharth Rout is perfectly fine, it would require quite a bit of string manipulation to get the date in a usable form.

For the above reason I'm providing an alternative solution which gets the date in a directly usable format, ready to be manipulated and used in further calculations if necessary.

As a bonus I am demonstrating how to get the date using an HTTP request instead of using the Internet Explorer. This makes the code more efficient.

```
Option Explicit

Sub getDate()
Dim req As New WinHttpRequest
Dim doc As New HTMLDocument
Dim el As HTMLParaElement
Dim key As String
Dim url As String
Dim retrievedDate As Date
url = "http://www.fechadehoy.com/venezuela"
key = "Fecha actual: "

''''''''''Bonus: Use an HTTP request to get the date instead of opening IE'''''''''''
With req                                                                            '
    .Open "GET", url, False                                                         '
    .send                                                                           '
    doc.body.innerHTML = .responseText                                              '
    'Debug.Print .responseText                                                       '
End With                                                                            '
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

For Each el In doc.getElementsByTagName("p")
    If el.innerText Like "Fecha actual*" Then
        retrievedDate = Mid(el.innerText, InStr(el.innerText, key) + Len(key), Len(el.innerText))
    End If
Next el

End Sub
```

You will need to add a reference to `Microsoft HTML Object Library`and `Microsoft WinHTTP Services version 5.1`. To do that, go to VB editor>Tools>References.

Having the date in this format, means it can easily be manipulated. An example would be the use of functions like `day(retrievedDate)` , `month(retrievedDate)`, `year(retrievedDate)` etc.

Comment: Add the library, but don't let me execute the code, "the type has not been defined by the user"

Comment: @EduardoGonzalez Sorry I forgot the second reference. I updated my answer. You also need a reference to `Microsoft WinHTTP Services version 5.1`

Comment: Thank you for your time, and your response was very helpful for my project. Have a nice day.

Comment: @EduardoGonzalez Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

if you need `Lunes, 19 de agosto de 2019` then use `getElementById` for `fecha`

[image]

```
Debug.Print IE.document.getElementById("fecha").Innerhtml
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Why go for IE when xhr can do the trick? You can get the date with the blink of an eye if you opt for `XMLHttpRequest`.

```
Sub GetCurrentDate()
    Dim S$

    With New XMLHTTP
        .Open "GET", "http://www.fechadehoy.com/venezuela", False
        .send
        S = .responseText
    End With

    With New HTMLDocument
        .body.innerHTML = S
        MsgBox .getElementById("fecha").innerText
    End With
End Sub
```

Reference to add:

```
Microsoft XML, v6.0
Microsoft HTML Object Library
```

[image]

To get rid of that reference altogether:

```
Sub GetCurrentDate()
    Dim S$

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "http://www.fechadehoy.com/venezuela", False
        .send
        S = .responseText
    End With

    With CreateObject("htmlfile")
        .body.innerHTML = S
        MsgBox .getElementById("fecha").innerText
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: It points to me as the error: "New XMLHTTP" and I have the error "not defined by the user"

Comment: I just updated the thread with another image can you check it?

Comment: Thank you for your time, and your response was very helpful for my project. Have a nice day.

Comment: Nice and clean +